# How would I Bypass ECourts Captcha Code in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I want to bypass the captcha code of another website in Vuejs. The link is generated dynamically for every captcha code and user has to enter everytime, so I want to bypass the captcha code.

I have the API key for that and the page URL also but the website is a bit old and the captcha which the website is using is siwp_captcha maybe the name has the changed till date but earlier the name was siwp_captcha

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of that *another website*? Why not just update the source code to allow certain user credentials or role to bypass captcha

Comment: I would like to bypass the security at the pentagon, at least I think that is what it was used to be called ..

Comment: I am not having the access of the another website source code , it is a public website and I am capturing the data but everytime I need to enter the captcha so I am unable to bypass the captcha of other website. Could you please help?